# android-java class not found exception

Tags: java, android

Could this be the reason of `exception`?

> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>        Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent      location 'C:\Users\shikhu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-      google-23-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\shikhu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23')
>
> Already observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in 'C:\Users\shikhu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23'.
>
> Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\shikhu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1'
>
> Observed package id 'system-images;android-22;google_apis;x86' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\shikhu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\addon-google_apis-google-22\x86' (Expected 'C:\Users\shikhu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86')
>
> Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

Comment: Use SDK Manager to remove all versions of Android SDK Build Tools 23.x , then SDK manager will show a single version 23 available to install.

Comment: when i am using usb degugging then only this exception occurs

Comment: Please specify what you'r trying to do and how you're doing it. At its current state your post is very vague.